# PyInstaller and PySide, how to include the imageformats folder?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyinstaller

I feel bad for asking two questions in an hour, but oh well.

I am building a fairly complex application using Python and PySide. Finally the day of the release is nearing so I want to build this application as an exe. I am using PyInstaller to build my exe binary.

A part of this application loads some JPEG images. I had problems loading these images into my application (they just wouldn't show up), so I had to do this:

```
path = os.getcwd()
app.addLibraryPath(path) #app being QApplication()
```

This made it work (this path contains the `imageformats` folder which contains the `qjpeg4.dll` and other image loading plugins)

However, now I ran into the same problem when packaging it with PyInstaller. I must use the `--onefile` flag, but even when I don't, I can see that PyInstaller did not include the `imageformats` folder - nowhere to be found.

I know that this is the problem because when I manually copy/paste the imageformats folder into the folder where the exe is located, the application works as expected.

Is there a way to *force* PyInstaller to include a folder I specify, specifically this imageformats folder?

Comment: Do you have your JPEG's in a Qt Resource file? Is the issue with finding qjpeg4.dll or with loading the images themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option when using PyInstaller, `--additional-hooks-dir=HOOKSDIR`, that will append additional directories to the pyinstaller search path.

Comment: PyInstaller user manual says "--additional-hooks-dir=HOOKSPATH Additional path to search for hooks. This will go into the extend the hookspath, see Analysis below."

Comment: So I don't think this answer is correct.  You would also need to write a custom hooks-module.    Wouldn't it be just as easy to modify the spec file to make it include the dll?

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller's option`--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>`

```
pyinstaller --add-data "\path\of\imageformats;imageformats" target.py
```